# EXC_ARITHMETIC when accessing random elements of NSArray

Tags: objective-c

i'm trying to get the values of an array randomly but i'm getting an error
here is my code so far:

```
NSMutableArray *validMoves = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    [validMoves removeAllObjects];

    for (TileClass *t in tiles ) {
        if ([self blankTile:t] != 0) {
            [validMoves addObject:t];
        }
    }

    NSInteger pick = arc4random() % validMoves.count;

    [self movePiece:(TileClass *)[validMoves objectAtIndex:pick] withAnimation:NO];
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: Don't use `arc4random() % n`. That suffers from modulo bias. Just use `arc4random_uniform(n)` instead. That returns a number in the range `[0,n)`, which is what you want, but without modulo bias.

Comment: it says build succeeded but when the iOS simulator pops up i get a message in my code : "Thread 1: EXC_ARITHMETIC (code = EXC_1386_DIV, Subcode = 0x0) pardon me, im just new in Xcode

Comment: @Tbt-lionArmanCapistrano: What line does it crash on?

Comment: @Tbt-lionArmanCapistrano that would likely imply that `validMoves.count` is `0`. Are you sure you have any valid moves when you perform that code? Try adding `NSLog(@"%@", validMoves);` to see the set from amongst which your code is making a choice.

Comment: it crashes on this line:  NSInteger pick =arc4random() % [validMoves count];

Comment: @Tommy i tried your code, here is the output 2012-12-11 09:57:03.508 TestSlidePuzzle[1415:c07] (
)
what does this mean?

Comment: @Tbt-lionArmanCapistrano: It means he was right, your `validMoves` is empty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error you're getting (an arithmetic exception) is because `validMoves` is empty and this leads to a division by zero when you perform the modulus operation.

You have to explicitly check for the case of an empty `validMoves` array.
Also you should use `arc4random_uniform` for avoiding modulo bias.

```
if (validMoves.count > 0) {
    NSInteger pick = arc4random_uniform(validMoves.count);
    [self movePiece:(TileClass *)[validMoves objectAtIndex:pick] withAnimation:NO];
} else {
   // no valid moves, do something reasonable here...
}
```

As a final remark not that `arc4random_uniform(0)` returns `0`, therefore such case should be avoided or you'll be trying to access the first element of an empty array, which of course will crash your application.

Comment: I was testing the same. Apparently the solution is to explicitly check for when `validMoves` is empty, since it would try to access the array at index 0 otherwise.

Comment: i got an error: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' i think there's a problem with my iteration

Comment: check my edited answer. You NEED to check for 0 since when validMoves is empty you're are always trying to access the first element of the array, due to the behavior of arc4random_uniform